# Is there any address validation api in node js?

Tags: node.js

I will just pass the parameters like street, city,country,zipcode etc. The api should check if the parameters are valid or not? is there any such api which works for us? I want to implement it in node js.

Comment: No, no such thing exists natively. You'll have to rely on external services or a downloadable database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/address-validator

Note that you also could use any other decicated third-part using http request